# System profiler gives incorrect cpu speed?

Tags: 14.04, cpu

When I check the System profiler and Benchmark application it gives me incorrect cpu speeds and the speeds tend to vary every time I run the application. Ranging from 1900 to 3900 (3900MHz is what I would expect it to say every time).

[image: asdf]

What do these values indicate? Was I wrong to expect the maximum speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU is clocked down if it is not used to save power. So there is nothing wrong with the tool It just shows the actual CPU frequency.
You could try to run:
`openssl speed`

Then you would see the first core to show 3900 Mhz in the System profiler and Benchmark application.
The reason for this is that openssl is only using one core.

You would need a benchmark which uses multiple cores so that all cores show 3900 Mhz.

If you want more infos on your CPU, run:
`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: I ran openssl speed as you said and it said that using md4 for example I could process 84765.30k bytes per second with 16 bytes blocks. The number drastically changes per algorithm used, so how do I deduce 3900MHz from this?

Comment: I edited my answer, so I hope it is clearer now :)